# Increase Firebase Cloud Firestore string upload size

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase and I am running into an error when I am trying to store a (large) data object into the database. Here is the exact error I am getting:

`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: The value of property "values" is longer than 1048487 bytes.`

This is because Firebase doesn't allow storage of strings larger than 1048487 bytes ([documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types)).

Is there a way to increase the store limit? From what I have read it doesn't seem like purchasing a plan will fix this.

Here is the code I am using to store the data just in case it's needed:

```
  storeSearchItem(searchItem, userID, data) {
    this.db.collection('users').doc(userID).collection('searches').add({
      searchTerm: searchItem.searchTerm,
      searchDate: new Date().toString(),
      values: data, //this values property is huge, a couple megabytes
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation is telling you there is a hard limit.  It can't be changed.  You will have to find a different way to store your data.